Dryer vent thru closed closet
We ran the dryer vent through the closed closet, as shown in the picture

However, after using the dryer, I noticed condensation forming. Initially, I suspected there might be gaps in the wall or vent, so I applied expanding foam to seal them. Unfortunately, this didn't help much. I then wrapped the vent with fiberglass insulation, but I still see condensation. Do you have any suggestions for fixing this without removing the closet? Or was this project a mistake from the beginning?

Where was the condensation coming from?  Maybe remove that insulation and feel for where you are getting drafts from your ductwork.  If the ductwork has leaks, close them up with aluminum seam sealing tape (not duct tape) first.

Condensation forms when warm moist air touches a cool surface.  Does your outside dryer vent have a cover/flapper to prevent cold air from coming in?  Dryer vents exhaust warm humid air, any chance some of that air is leaking into the cooler cabinet?

I noticed condensation forming ... where?

One more question: what kind of pipe or hose did you use? (There’s rigid, flexible foil and spring loaded plastic, to name the big ones.)
